# Changing div colour if child button is the same as button clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery, I am using a .net component to create an organisational chart which each member of the chart has a button. I want to change the color of the DIV containing the button and also any other DIV which has the same button.

For example in my code below if the button 77770001 was selected then i would like to change the surrounding DIV rocItemTemplate to a different colour but also any other div which has a child with the same value. Can anyone help?

```
<div id="RadOrgChart1" class="RadOrgChart RadOrgChart_Default">
<!-- 2012.1.301.40 --><div class="rocViewPort" style="visibility: hidden; width: 800px; ">
    <ul class="rocNodeList rocRootNodeList" style="width: 780px; visibility: visible; ">
        <li class="rocNode rocRootNode" style="width: 770px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
            <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl43$LinkButtonNode" value="02079891000" id="ctl43_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

            </div>
        </div><ul class="rocNodeList rocLevel1" style="width: 770px; ">
            <li class="rocNode rocFirst rocLast rocOnly" style="width: 770px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl47$LinkButtonNode" value="77770001" id="ctl47_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                </div>
            </div><ul class="rocNodeList rocLevel2" style="width: 770px; ">
                <li class="rocNode rocFirst" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                    <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" value="01494561123" name="ctl51$LinkButtonNode" id="ctl51_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                    </div>
                </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                    <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                </div></li><li class="rocNode" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                    <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl54$LinkButtonNode" value="77770001" id="ctl54_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                    </div>
                </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                    <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                </div></li><li class="rocNode" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                    <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl57$LinkButtonNode" value="77770002" id="ctl57_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                    </div>
                </div><ul class="rocNodeList rocLevel3" style="width: 120px; ">
                    <li class="rocNode rocFirst rocLast rocOnly" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                        <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl61$LinkButtonNode" value="0061422226212" id="ctl61_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                        </div>
                    </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                        <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                    </div></li>
                </ul><div class="rocNodeLines">
                    <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineDown"><!-- --></span>
                </div></li><li class="rocNode rocLast" style="width: 380px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                    <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" name="ctl64$LinkButtonNode" value="77770003" id="ctl64_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                    </div>
                </div><ul class="rocNodeList rocLevel3" style="width: 380px; ">
                    <li class="rocNode rocFirst" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                        <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" value="0061431540656" name="ctl68$LinkButtonNode" id="ctl68_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                        </div>
                    </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                        <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                    </div></li><li class="rocNode" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                        <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" value="0061883836198" name="ctl71$LinkButtonNode" id="ctl71_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                        </div>
                    </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                        <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                    </div></li><li class="rocNode rocLast" style="width: 120px; "><div class="rocItem rocNoOwnImage">
                        <div class="rocItemTemplate">


           <input type="submit" value="0061883836255" name="ctl74$LinkButtonNode" id="ctl74_LinkButtonNode" class="middle">

                        </div>
                    </div><div class="rocNodeLines">
                        <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span>
                    </div></li>
                </ul><div class="rocNodeLines">
                    <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineDown"><!-- --></span>
                </div></li>
            </ul><div class="rocNodeLines">
                <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineDown"><!-- --></span>
            </div></li>
        </ul><div class="rocNodeLines">
            <span class="rocLineHorizontal"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineUp"><!-- --></span><span class="rocLineDown"><!-- --></span>
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div><input id="RadOrgChart1_ClientState" name="RadOrgChart1_ClientState" type="hidden">
```

Edit:

I should also say that when the button is clicked all the others which do not contain the number clicked must be changed to a different class

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('div:contains([type="submit"][value="' + value + '"])').addClass("yourCssClassSpecifyingTheColor");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('input[value=77770001]').closest('div').css('background-color',"Red");
```